# How to read/write AVR EEprom memory from C# windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

need help..
 I my application I need to write/read text box data to AVR microcontroller eeprom memory 
through USB communication.how to do it....

Comment: First you should decide what particular model of an AVR MCU you have (Atmel lists no less than six MCU families under the "AVR" nomer). Then you might want to Google for some .NET library, C/C++ library or commandline tool that does the job. And only then make plans about calling/pinvoking that library or commandline tool from within your C# application...

Comment: I am using Xmega 256A3BU controller

Comment: I suppose your MCU uses the DFU bootloader. If so, you might look into the "[DFU Programmer](https://github.com/dfu-programmer/dfu-programmer/wiki)", which has a commandline tool which can dump Flash as well as Eeprom to stdout (in your C# application you can then capture/read the output on stdout without requiring to create a temp file). I would suggest that you become accustomed with this tool before starting with C# programming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an USART<--> USB converter first for the AVR doesn't have an USB controller on board (check [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8077.pdf)). You can buy ready-to-use cables (e.g. RS232 <-> USB) or if you are fine with electronics you can easily build your own interface just buying one of those cheap interface chips. The needed driver (if not using the default system driver) is already included most of the time. The converter then wraps the USB up into a common serial communication port. In your system the USB will appear as a COM port. You then could use the [SerialPort class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to handle the communication. The actual memory writing is coded into your avr using C language. This code needs to be written by yourself. The AVR has access to the data via the USART interface. Common technique is to use the controller side interrupts for reading/ writing to the USART port.

If you want to use the USB interface directly without emulating a COM port you have to write your own USB driver which is responsible for accessing the bus system. It will register your device etc.
If you don't need the full USB features but only want to do some simple communication or data transfer it is enough to use a converter.